# sql - Add column(foreign key to one of the table) to all tables in databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a new column to all tables in db which is a foreign key to one of the table. Ideally I should add the column to all tables instead of the table that the foreign key reference to.

How do I combine these two SQL statements to only one statement?

```
// Get all tables except the foreign key reference to
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="arthurMurray"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
AND TABLE_NAME!="Competitions";

// Add compeition_id to table as a foreign key to competitions table
ALTER TABLE t
ADD competition_id INTEGER,
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(competition_id) REFERENCES Competitions(id);
```

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Do you really need to add it to *every* table? I doubt every other table in your database has a **direct** one-to-many relationship with a competition. For example, you have many hotels and hotels have many rooms. A room also has many bookings. You don't need to directly relate a booking and a hotel, as you can find the relationship from the room; as a room only belong to one hotel.

Comment: It is not common use case to add same foreign key to all tables. actually I can say that you must not do that unless you are really sure about what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
if not exists (select * from sys.columns 
               where object_id = object_id(''?'')
               and name = ''CreatedOn'') 
begin
    ALTER TABLE ? ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
end';
```

Comment: That doesn't have a Foreign Key.

Comment: Adding Foreign key to all table will not work when already values are available in the several tables. It might cause error.

Answer (score 0):

you ca use below query to generate your alter statement then you ca copy paste and execute below script.

```
SELECT 
  'ALTER TABLE ' +  TABLE_NAME + 'ADD competition_id INTEGER,  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(competition_id) REFERENCES Competitions(id);'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='whatever_schema'
  AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_NAME!='Competitions';
```